# Push notification em app hibrido

Tags: php, android, webview, push-notification

Estou criando um app hibrido Android, que é na verdade uma webview rodando um sistema, hospedado em algum servidor, feito em php.

Preciso implantar um sistema de notificação (Push Notification) que envie notificações personalizadas para usuários específicos cadastrado no sistema.

Um Script PHP vai ser rodado de tanto em tanto tempo no servidor e este irá analisar para quais usuários enviará uma notificação baseada em algumas regras que colocarei.

É possível fazer?
Qual a melhor ferramenta para utilizar?
Alguém teria algum tutorial para indicar?

Comment: É possível. A melhor ferramenta eu não sei, eu uso o [`firebase`](https://firebase.google.com) do próprio google. Links que podem te ajudar: [Configurar Cloud Messaging em um applicativo android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?hl=pt-br), [Projeto exemplo do Cloud Messaging](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging)

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tudo bem!?

Mesmo sendo apenas uma webView no Android, vc pode implementar algumas classes e tornar nativo:

1. Classe para fazer uma requisição no servidor e salvar o id do celular
2. Outra casse para receber a notificação.

Primeiro de faça os imports do Firebase no build.gradle (Module: app), partindo do pressuposto que já está usando o firebase no seu projeto, pois tem outros passos básicos necessários para funcionar (aqueles que o firebase te ensina a configurar quando vc cria o projeto no console):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
```

Será necessário esses seguintes parametros no seu manifest dentro da tag application (junto com a declaração das activitys).

```
<!--notificação -->
<service
    android:name=".FCM.FCMInstanceIdService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service
    android:name=".FCM.FCMService" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Em seguida será necessário criar as classes para o FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)

FCMInstanceIdService.java: para gerar o token unico do aparelho. Esse grava token, é para gravar no meu servidor próprio, caso nao use apague essa classe):

```
/**
 * Criado por Leonardo Figueiredo em 20/08/2018.
 */
public class FCMInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

public static String TAG = "FirebaseLog";
String refreshedToken;

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();
    refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    gravaToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Token: " + refreshedToken);
}

public void gravaToken() {
    TokenModel tokenModel = new TokenModel();
    tokenModel.setTokenDevice(refreshedToken);
    tokenModel.setSo("Android");

    Call<TokenModel> call = new RetrofitConfig().getApiCandidato().gravaToken(tokenModel.getTokenDevice(), tokenModel.getSo());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<TokenModel>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TokenModel> call, Response<TokenModel> response) {
            //sucesso
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TokenModel> call, Throwable t) {
            //falha
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Agora será necessário a classe FCMService.java: será responsável por receber e tratar a notificação.

```
/**
 * Criado por Leonardo Figueiredo em 20/08/2018.
 */
public class FCMService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

public static String TAG = "FirebaseLog";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    Log.v(TAG, "recebeu mensagem do firebase");

    //verifica se recebeu alguma notificacao
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        String mensagem = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PrincipalActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
                .setContentTitle(String.valueOf(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notificacao)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_logo_color))
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(mensagem))
                .setContentText(mensagem)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(99, builder.build());
        Log.d(TAG, "Menssagem: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}
}
```

Agora basta ir no seu console do firebase, vá no menu Ampliar -> Cloud Messaging.
Caso deseje enviar diretamente pelo seu scrip, veja nesse link o passo a passo, para que automatize e envie pelo seu script: https://gist.github.com/rolinger/d6500d65128db95f004041c2b636753a

Preencha os dados e envie e seja feliz.

OBS.: Coloque um breakpoint na classe FCMInstanceIdService e verifique se ele gerou uma hash, esse é o id exclusivo do seu aparelho (só acontece na primeira vez que instala o App).

Antes de enviar coloque um breakpoint na classe FCMService, pois é nela que irá chegar a mensagem.